# What does "tied up in a cotton handkerchief" mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across this phrase in *The Legend of Sleepy Hollow* by Washington Irving:

> The revenue arising from his school was small, and would have been
> scarcely sufficient to furnish him with daily bread, for he was a huge
> feeder, and, though lank, had the dilating powers of an anaconda; but
> to help out his maintenance, he was, according to country custom in
> those parts, boarded and lodged at the houses of the farmers whose
> children he instructed. With these he lived successively a week at a
> time, thus going the rounds of the neighborhood, **with all his
> worldly effects tied up in a cotton handkerchief**.

I interpret "cotton handkerchief" to be related to consumption of food, but am not sure what it means to be "tied up" in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means literally what it says: He had so few possessions ("worldly effects") that he was able to carry all of them by laying them on a handkerchief (which was made of cotton) and tying the corners of the handkerchief together so that it formed a loose bag.

If you then take this bag and tie it to, or hang it from, the end of a stick, you have a *bindle*, the classic "hobo" method of carrying possessions, as shown in [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bindle#/media/File:Hobos2.jpg).